# Problem with custom error messages for field validation in Marshmallow

Tags: python, json, flask, marshmallow

I'm trying to add a customized error message for a class field in Marshamallow's schema. The field representation looks like this:

```
phone_number = fields.String(validate=Length(max=20),
                             error_messages={'invalid': 'Phone number must be a string shorter than'
                                                        '20 letters.'})
```

I was expecting that after loading the request data to a schema, I would get the error "Phone number must be a string shorter than 20 letters.", however, I'm still receiving the default message "Longer than maximum length 20.". The code for loading the request data is:

```
        try:
            request_data = EditInvestorSchema().load(request.json)
        except ValidationError as error:
            return get_response(400, list(error.messages.values())[0])
```

Can anyone shed some light on what might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define the message in the validator it should work.
See [here](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshmallow.validate.html#marshmallow.validate.Length) for the documentation of the validator.

```
phone_number = fields.String(
    validate=Length(
        max=20, 
        error='Phone number must be a string shorter than 20 letters.'
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works properly! The 'invalid' error message reffers to the field type instead of the validator function!